# copied object doesn't print _rawValue in console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

```
const a = ref(new A()); 

const test = () => {
const b = { ...a };

console.log(a); //  RefImpl{_v_isShallow: false, _dep: sth, _v_isRef: true, _rawValue: sth, _value: sth} 
console.log(b); // {_v_isShallow: false, _dep: sth, _v_isRef: true, _rawValue: sth, _value: sth} 
console.log(a.value); prints value 
console.log(b.value); undefined
}
```

everything in `{}` from both `console.log(a), console.log(b)` is same except `a` is wrapped in `RefImpl`

I'm not sure why b.value is coming as undefined.

any suggestions?

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: It's a mistake to use refs like that. It's undefined because `value` is a getter in case of a ref and it's not taken into account when an object is copied

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you first of all. Ah... that makes sense.. what should I do if I'm using ref wrong? I'm trying to give my "a" a default model value if data was not given from API.

Comment: Can you explain how they are related? In your case `a` value is already Ref instance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean by your first sentence(in which context?). A is a class I have in another file if that's what you are asking. I'm trying to copy a into b, and use b as a write model for API request.

Comment: Consider explaining your case further, regarding `a` and `b`, it's unclear how this applies to the situation with default value. The question is XY problem and doesn't make this clear. Basically ref value is copied as `b.value = a.value`

Comment: I'm just trying to deep copy a into b. When I change the value of b, a's value should remain the same.

Comment: The question doesn't cover this this, `{ ...a }` makes shallow copy and clones ref object. It's unclear how is it supposed to work. You can't make a copy of random class without the risk of breaking it, it's always depends on the implementation. It's unknown why a class is used, they aren't very useful in Vue, and you wouldn't have this problem with plain objects. Consider reasking the question with relevant details. It's XY problem at this point, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is best to avoid trying to copy ref objects to each other directly like this as the intended use is as a reference to a single element / value you can assign or manipulate directly.

If you want to make a copy so that you have two distinct refs that share the same value, but can be modified separately without impacting each other, you would instantiate like this -

```
const a = ref(new A());
const b = ref(a.value);
```